# Why are there empty spaces to the right and bottom of the grid even when all grid elements are sized using fr?

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I created a square container div  with variable numbers of square div children. Using grid, these divs were supposed to fill up the entirety of the container div, and they were sized using `column-template-columns: repeat(#divs per side of square, 1fr)` and `grid auto rows: 1fr`, with there being #divs per side of square ^ 2 div children in total.

The problem occurs when certain numbers of divs are added to the container. Basically, a strange gap appears to the right and bottom of the container such that the divs do not fully fill out the container despite everything being sized using fr units. For example, this occurs when there are 71 ^ 2 divs added to the container.

Here's the code:

```js
const INITIAL_SIZE = 71;
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

for (let i = 0; i < INITIAL_SIZE * INITIAL_SIZE; i++) {
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.classList.add("drawing-div");
  container.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(71, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.drawing-div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: gray;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

I've already checked the margins/paddings/borders/etc.: None of the divs in the container have any of that--it seems to be a sizing issue, with the widths of all the inner divs added together not equalling the width of the container div for certain numbers of inner divs. Why is this?

Comment: remove the fixed width

Comment: I don't see anything when I run your code.

Comment: @Barmar my bad--forgot to color it in

Comment: I just see a grey square, without any gaps.

Comment: @Barmar seems like it appears and disappears based on viewport size and zoom.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const INITIAL_SIZE = 71;
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

for (let i = 0; i < INITIAL_SIZE * INITIAL_SIZE; i++) {
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.classList.add("drawing-div");
  container.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(71, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap:2px;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  background-color: RGB(255, 255, 255);
}

.drawing-div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: background-color 0.15s;
  background:blue;
  padding-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Could you help clarify what was wrong with my original snippet?

Comment: @tqtqtwtw don't you check his css ?

Comment: @tqtqtwtw you define fixed width/height and i removed them to have a responsive block

Comment: @MisterJojo I did, just not sure how it fixes the problem conceptually. Am I misunderstanding how fr works, or is there some other gap in my understanding?

Comment: @nothing I understand that, but for various reasons the block needs to be that height and width, and all resizing needs to be done on the divs inside.

Comment: Don't just post code and expect people to see the difference. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it. And do it in the answer, not comments.